# Disabling button connected to listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box and when there are no items in it I want the button to not be enabled. This is the code I have at the moment

`If lstMarks.Items.Count = -1 Then
            btnShowMean.Enabled = False
        End If`

However even when there is nothing in the list box you can still press the button. What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count will never be less than zero:

```
If lstMarks.Items.Count = 0 Then
  btnShowMean.Enabled = False
End If
```

or just:

```
btnShowMean.Enabled = (lstMarks.Items.Count > 0)
```

Comment: The button is still enabled when there is nothing in the list box

Comment: At the end of the click event for the button

Comment: Private Sub btnShowMean_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowMean.Click
        Dim Mean As Double
        Mean = Total / NumberOfMarks
        lblMean.Text = Mean
        btnShowMean.Enabled = (lstMarks.Items.Count > 0)
        
    End Sub

Comment: @Todd432 If the button is enabled, then there are items in the lstMarks control.  Your code isn't doing anything with the items in the ListBox anyway, so it's not clear why something would change.

Comment: When I launch the program I set enabled to false, and when I add an item to the list box the button then becomes enabled, however when I clear the items in the list box the button does not go back to enabled = false which is what I want

Comment: @Todd432 Where are you clearing the items in the ListBox?  I can't see that code.  btnShowMean_Click isn't clearing anything.

Comment: Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lstMarks.Items.Clear()
        lblMean.Text = ""
    End Sub

Comment: @Todd432 Why wouldn't you just put `btnShowMean.Enabled = False` at the end of that btnClear_Click code?

Comment: That has now worked, but do you know why the other method was not working?

Comment: @Todd432 lstMarks wasn't clear yet when you clicked the btnShowMean button.